# Trouble moving elements dynamically within Avada theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create dynamic categories in our wordpress site, but within our Avada theme. I have the PHP working fine for pulling the category information, but what is proving a challenge is placing the divs correctly. I.e., I can get the dynamic categories on the page, but in the wrong spot.

I've tried creating the divs, placing them in a parent DIV of my creation and then appending them to the right spot in the DOM, but that either doesn't work or gives this error:

```
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.
```

Here's a quick look at the JS/jQuery I've tried. Essentially my intent is to find #dynamicDiv and all the divs within, set them to a variable and then append them below the title bar inside the .fusion class. 
It's possible I'm way off, so any help is much appreciated.

```
   var selection =jQuery("#dynamicDiv").find("div");
    var div =jQuery(".fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box fusion-blend-mode hundred-percent-fullwidth").find(".fusion-title title fusion-title-size-one");
    jQuery(div).append(selection);
```

Comment: You realise `find('div')` will get **all** divs within the `#dynamicDiv` right?

Comment: The chances are, one of the `find()`'s is failing to target something correctly. Double check to make sure that the divs you're wanting to target is actually working.

Comment: The idea would be to move everything within  `dynamicDiv` to a spot lower in the page. So yes, I think I'd want to move all of them. I could be wrong, though.